# JQ validation: hide error container

Tags: jquery, validation, hide

The error container DIV with general error message is shown automatically because it is specified in validation defaults:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    ........
    errorContainer: ".valerror",
    ........
});
```

This container has only a general "Check your input" message and should not contain messages specific for every input control. When I click the submit button without filling the form, invalid fields are marked and general error message is shown. As fields are filled they are unmarked, but general error message remains.

Now the problem: I need to hide the container when all the fields become valid (without pressing the submit button again).

I tried

```
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        if (this.numberOfInvalids() == 0) {
            $(".valerror").hide();
        }
    },
```

but this block of code deranges the normal functioning of validation engine completely, because it does not know anything about "unhighlight".

**Accepted answer**

I copied "unhighlight" and "highlight" handlers from JQuery validation plug-in source code to my code and the validation functionality was restored.

```
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // default handling
        if (element.type === 'radio') {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
        // custom handling
        $("#errnum").html(this.numberOfInvalids());
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // default handling
        if (element.type === 'radio') {
            this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
        // custom handling
        $("#errnum").html(this.numberOfInvalids());
    },
```

Knowing the number of validation errors remaining helped me to figure out that the error container is hided automatically by JQ validation plugin and that the problem was in some dependent slave SELECTs which were not revalidating on changing of master SELECTs (but highlighting was removed from slaves).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're doing something else wrong, that you're not showing us in your examples above.  `errorContainer` is documented like this:

> Uses an additonal container for error messages. The elements given as
>   the errorContainer are all shown and hidden when errors occur

i.e. validate handles showing and hiding whatever you specify as the errorContainer.  And you can see here, that it does in fact handle it correctly:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/neugH/

If that doesn't help, you'll need to modify your question to provide more code... likely the rest of the options you're providing to $.validate and any other JS attached to the form.